What is the effectiveness of the Gardasil Vaccine after 1 or 2 or 3 doses?
What is the effectiveness of the Gardasil Vaccine on various dose schedules? How does it vary with age?
The Public Health Agency of Canada updated it’s immunization guide, National Advisory Committee on Immunization recently updated guidelines for HPV immunization, and the World Health Organization to only a two dose schedule of Gardasil-9 for patients who are not immunocompromised. However, none of these notices go into detail on the rationale for the decision, and some only specifically recommend the 2 dose schedule for people aged 9-26 years old.
My question is how do different dose schedules vary in their effectiveness? For patients on dose 2 of the 3 dose schedule (ie they have received 2 doses two months apart) what's the benefit to getting the final dose?

I edited your question to make it one question. You can ask the other questions separately if you wish. I hope you don't mind but I thought that better than closing your question for needing more focus because it asked multiple questions.

I think the question specifically asking what people on dose 2 of 3 in a 3 dose schedule is very useful and timely. Is it possible under the rules to leave that one in?

Sure! Just [edit] your question and add that wording, but please try to make it focused on just one question.

The clinical trials go into how effective it is and what schedules were worked out. This one might be a good place to start.
